Theorem of calculus valid for improper integrals.
Suppose we have a function $I$ defined as $$I(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\;dx$$ and to have proven that it is derivable for all $t>0$. Then we have that $$I'(t)=-\frac{1}{1+t^2}.$$
I have to calculate $I(t)$ for all $t\in (0,\infty)$. It seems natural to me to proceed like this:
\begin{align}
I(t)=\int_0^\infty -\frac{1}{1+t^2}\;dt=-\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^c\frac{1}{1+t^2}\;dt=\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}
A question comes to me spontaneously: is the fundamental theorem of calculus valid for improper integrals?

$I(t)$ is unlikely to be constant, so you might reconsider the limits on your integration.

@HanryThanks, I'm really confused now. Could you kindly give me a hint?

You would usually expect $I(t)$ to vary with $t$ if $I'(t)\not=0$. The equivalent of the fundamental theorem of calculus would be $I(t)=I(0)+\int\limits_0^t I'(s),ds$ and I think if $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} I(t) =0$ then $I(t)=-\int\limits_t^\infty I'(s),ds$.

@Henry Sorry, there's something I'm missing or don't remember. Why if $\lim_{t\to\infty}I(t)=0$, then $I(t)=-\int_t^\infty I'(s);ds$?

Because  $\int\limits_t^r I'(s),ds = I(r) - I(t)$ and so (abusing notation) $\int\limits_t^\infty I'(s),ds = I(\infty) - I(t)$
